# Writing to a servlet from a java class and reading from another application

Tags: java

I want my java class , which has the processed information , to write to a servlet. Then I want the separate module to read this information from the servlet. Is it possible to do so?

In many examples I found writing to a servlet and getting back the response to the same java class. I want the content which has written to the servlet to remain until my other application reads from it.

Please , any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need something like a Message Bus?

Comment: _I want my java class_ —post your class? _processed information_ —what kind of information is that? _the separate module_ —can you tell something about it? _In many examples_ —give us a link/links to it/them. ... What I've wanted to say, is that you have to put more effort into the question, so that _we_ can make _any_ effort into giving you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet needs a queue or stack to store the information.

Provide one method to push an entry.

Provide another method to pull an entry.